# Передача геолокации яндекс карт в приложение яндекс навигатор

Tags: api

Подскажите есть ли в api карт возможность имея код геолокации точка отправки и точка прибытия - отправить сведения по данным точкам в яндекс навигатор в приложении на устройстве?

Comment: Для этого вам нужно использовать модуль "Маршрутизация"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в API Яндекс.Карт есть возможность отправки запроса на построение маршрута между двумя точками с помощью геолокации и отображения маршрута в Яндекс.Навигаторе на устройстве пользователя. Для этого вам нужно использовать Яндекс.Карты API, а именно модуль "Маршрутизация".

Вот пример запроса для построения маршрута между двумя точками с помощью Яндекс.Карты API:

```
ymaps.route([точка отправки, точка прибытия]).then(function (route) {
  // Открываем Яндекс.Навигатор для отображения маршрута
  route.getPaths().options.set('mapStateAutoApply', true);
  ymaps.balloon.open(route.getPaths().get(0).getSegments()[0].getCoordinates(), {
    contentHeader: route.getActiveRoute().properties.get('name'),
    contentBody: route.getActiveRoute().properties.get('description'),
    contentFooter: '<a href="yandexnavi://show-route/?' + route.getActiveRoute().getPaths()[0].getPoints() + '">Открыть в Яндекс.Навигаторе</a>'
  });
}, function (error) {
  console.log('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message);
});
```

В этом примере мы используем метод `route()` модуля "Маршрутизация", чтобы построить маршрут между двумя точками, заданными координатами точки отправки и точки прибытия. Затем мы открываем балун с информацией о маршруте и ссылкой для открытия маршрута в Яндекс.Навигаторе.

Обратите внимание, что для использования Яндекс.Карты API и модуля "Маршрутизация" вам необходимо зарегистрироваться на сайте Яндекс.Девелопер и получить API-ключ. Подробнее о регистрации и получении API-ключа можно узнать на странице https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/.